# Extended monitor scaling

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, xrandr

I have a Dell XPS 13 running Ubuntu 15.04 with a `3200x1800` display and an external `1920x1200` monitor that is connected via DVI through a mini displayport adapter.  The UI on the built-in display is too small, while the UI on the external monitor is too big.  I'm having trouble getting the scaling to work nicely.

When I try using the generic scaling settings, I can scale down the appearance for the external monitor and I can get it looking nice.  However, when I adjust the scale for the built-in display, it adjusts the scale for *both* of the displays.  Everything is microscopic on the built-in display because of the high DPI, and when I scale it up to a reasonable level, it scales up the UI on the external monitor as well.  This doesn't make sense because when I change the scaling of the external monitor, the built-in display is not effected.

I've tried scaling up the built-in display and then using `xrandr` to scale the external monitor to `1.25x1.25`.  This works, however the mouse is then constrained to about 3/4 of the screen.  I've read most of the articles I can find online concerning this problem and it doesn't seem like there is a solution.

The only thing that seems to work is to use `xrandr` to scale the built-in display to a scale of `0.6x0.6`, but this looks like it is just zoomed-in and everything is slightly blurry which doesn't look nice.

Do I have any other options?

Comment: I have the same issue running 18.04 LTS on the latest XPS 13 9380.